# can i limit a tradingview strategy to only short/long if the last order was the opposite

Tags: pine-script

I've been coding my strategy in pinescript and all is well apart from 1 thing that i can't work out.

Is there a way to tell the strategy to only long if the last entry was a short and visa versa?

EDIT: apologies for the not adding the right code below before but it was because i never saw that it wouldn't allow me to save it as i didn't have enough info in the post.

My current code is:

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Script", overlay = true)

ma = ema(close, 200)

// Base condition
aboveMa = close > ma
belowMa = close < ma

//long conditions
threeAboveMa = aboveMa[1] and aboveMa[2] and aboveMa[3]
first3AboveMa = not aboveMa[4] and threeAboveMa

//short conditions
threeBelowMa = belowMa[1] and belowMa[2] and belowMa[3]
first3BelowMa = not belowMa[4] and threeBelowMa

// Debugging
plot(ma)
plotchar(aboveMa, "aboveMa", ".", location.top)
plotchar(threeAboveMa, "threeAboveMa", "•", location.top)
plotchar(first3AboveMa, "first3AboveMa", "▲", location.top)

// Debugging
plot(ma)
plotchar(belowMa, "aboveMa", ".", location.bottom)
plotchar(threeBelowMa, "threeAboveMa", "•", location.bottom)
plotchar(first3BelowMa, "first3AboveMa", "▲", location.bottom)

// The Fixed Percent Stop Loss Code
// User Options to Change Inputs (%)
stopPer = input(8.0, title='Stop Loss %', type=input.float) / 100
takePer = input(8.0, title='Take Profit %', type=input.float) / 100

// Determine where you've entered and in what direction
longStop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopPer)
shortStop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + stopPer)
shortTake = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - takePer)
longTake = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takePer)

//TRAILING STOP CODE
trailStop = input(title="Long Trailing Stop (%)", type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=10) * 0.01

longStopPrice = 0.0
shortStopPrice = 0.0
longStopPrice := if strategy.position_size > 0
    stopValue = close * (1 - trailStop)
    max(stopValue, longStopPrice[1])
else
    0
shortStopPrice := if strategy.position_size < 0
    stopValue = close * (1 + trailStop)
    min(stopValue, shortStopPrice[1])
else
    999999

//Long Entry
entrylong() => threeAboveMa
exitlong() => first3AboveMa

//Short Entry
entryshort() => threeBelowMa
exitshort() => first3AboveMa


if (threeAboveMa)
    strategy.entry(id = "long_ma", long = true, when = entrylong())
if (threeBelowMa)
    strategy.entry(id = "short_ma", long = false, when = entryshort())

if (threeAboveMa)
    strategy.exit(id = "exit_long", stop=longStop, limit=longTake)
if (threeBelowMa)
    strategy.exit(id = "exit_short", stop=shortStop, limit=shortTake)


//strategy.entry(id = "long_ma", long = true, when = entry())
//strategy.close(id = "long_ma", when = exit())
```

Comment: Could you please modify your script so that it compiles? Also, you forgot the `//@version=4` line.

Comment: i've now added the line. it compiles fine for me so not sure what you mean?

Comment: Certain variables are not present in your script.  line 44: Undeclared identifier 'longStop';
line 44: Undeclared identifier 'longTake';
line 46: Undeclared identifier 'shortStop';
line 46: Undeclared identifier 'shortTake'

Comment: so sorry, i don't know why i didn't add those variables. should be ok now

Comment: You still have not added them. Please post your whole script as you have it in your editor.

Comment: i did but it wouldn't allow me to save the post but didn't see the error message so didn't think anything of it. its 100% complete now